# How to combine two windows ascii text files with a cmd for loop?

Tags: regex, powershell

I've been trying to find a solution to this but can't find any . Maybe someone has an idea on this.

I have **file1.txt** which has one value per each line, and another **file2.txt** which has other values  on each line.

**file1.txt**

```
green
blue
red
[etc]
```

**file2.txt**

```
1
2
3
[etc]
```

I am trying to add all the values from file2.txt to the END of each of the values from file1.txt

The final output file will look like this

**output.txt**

```
green1
green2
green3
blue1
blue2
blue3
red1
red2
red3
[etc]
```

I've tried this in Excel to copy the values but it crashes.

Ideally i'm looking for a way to do this on **Windows**: maybe a PowerShell command, or a regex expression somehow with a cmd prompt command?

As these 2 files have lots of data, i don't see it working with Excel as it crashes constantly.

Don't look at 1,2,3 as a pattern in file2.txt, they can be anything other than numbers; so there is no pattern there; it's just diff values compared to file1.txt

Would greatly appreciate any solution on this,

Thank you!

PS: in some cases I have 500k lines on file1.txt, and 1000 lines on file2.txt; ideally I'd only use a cmd prompt or PowerShell command to work with the files..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 64-bit

cmd:

```
cd.> file3.txt
for /f %a in (file1.txt) do for /f %b in (file2.txt) do echo %a%b>> file3.txt 
file3.txt
```

script:

```
cd.> file3.txt
for /f %%a in (file1.txt) do for /f %%b in (file2.txt) do echo %%a%%b>> file3.txt
file3.txt
```

Comment: do you know how I can make it add at the BEGINNING of the file? i.e. add file2.txt values at the beginning of each of the values in file1.txt? Thank you!

Comment: @dou for /f %%a in (file1.txt) do for /f %%b in (file2.txt) do echo %%b%%a>> file3.txt